# \n not working in my fwrite()

Tags: php, file, file-io, newline

Not sure what could be the problem.

I'm dumping data from an array `$theArray` into `theFile.txt`, each array item on a separate line.

```
$file = fopen("theFile.txt", "w");
foreach ($theArray as $arrayItem){
    fwrite($file, $arrayItem . '\n');
}
fclose($file);
```

**Problem is** when I open `theFile.txt`, I see the `\n` being outputted literally. 
Also if I try to programmatically read the file line by line (just in case lines are there), it shows them as 1 line meaning `\n` are really not having their desired effect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Enclose `\n` in double quotes as `"\n"`

Inside a single quote a `\n` is treated as a literal slash followed by an n, but inside a double quote it is interpreted as a newline char.

Answer (score 2):

Single quotes do not process anything inside the quotes. Any '$' or escaped characters will appear exactly as they are printed with no modification (unless you run them through a function. You will have to use double quotes in order for the '\n' to appear as a line break in the file.